# Installing setuptools and pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm new to Python. Trying install `pip`. All tutorials I saw say me to install `setuptools` first before installing `pip`.
But I have read, that `pip` is a replacement for `setuptools`.

So, why I have to install `setuptools` first and only then I can install `pip`?

Comment: When I started out I also felt this was strange that a package manager is required to install another package manager. I am also curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pip is not a replacement for setuptools, quite the contrary, it heavily depends on it and always will depend on it for installing packages from source. What pip *does* replace is the `easy_install` tool, which is provided as part of setuptools for historical reasons but shouldn't be used any more.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install setuptools in order to have easy_install package manager that allows you to install third party packages from pypi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi).

Pip is another package manager but it's more powerful, for instance, you can dump all the installed packages, install packages from a tar.gz, etc.